# nodejs(forever) "ENOSPC"

Tags: node.js, forever

I have problem with forever. My script was stopped. I can't run it by:

```
forever start 1
```

I recived:

```
warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
info:    Forever processing file: 1
error:   Cannot start forever
error:   script /root/1 does not exist.
```

I tried to run it again by:

```
forever start forever.json
```

Forever.json:

```
{
    "uid": "roulette",
    "append": true,
    "watch": true,
    "script": "index.js",
    "sourceDir": "/home/user/domains/roulette/node/",
    "logFile": "/home/user/domains/roulette/logs/forever.log",
    "outFile": "/home/user/domains/roulette/logs/out.log",
    "errFile": "/home/user/domains/roulette/logs/err.log",
    "command": "node --expose-gc"
}
```

I found in log:

```
events.js:154
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: watch /home/user/domains/roulette/node/node_modules/socket.io-adapter/node_modules/socket.io-parser/bench/index.js ENOSPC
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:856:11)
    at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:1313:19)
    at Object.fs.watch (fs.js:1341:11)
    at createFsWatchInstance (/usr/lib/node_modules/forever/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:37:15)
    at setFsWatchListener (/usr/lib/node_modules/forever/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:80:15)
    at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._watchWithNodeFs (/usr/lib/node_modules/forever/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:228:14)
    at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._handleFile (/usr/lib/node_modules/forever/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:255:21)
    at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/forever/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:473:21)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
```

I set my /tmp directory:

```
npm config set tmp /home/user/tmp
```

But after few days it crashed again. I have lot of space on drive.

Anyone know what's happened there?

Answer (score 0):

Try nano-server instead lite-server

Thanks to Vrael
from [Quickstart with Angular 2.0.0-beta.6 doesn't work](http://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7138)